# Tensorflow JS errors in object detection in an image using a browser

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, object-detection-api

I am trying to detect objects in an image using tensorflow js.

I followed the tutorial in here [Tensorflow Object Detection with Tensorflow 2: Creating a custom model](https://gilberttanner.com/blog/tensorflow-object-detection-with-tensorflow-2-creating-a-custom-model)

So everything works fine in google collab and object detection works fine.

I get a saved_model, which I now would like to use on a browser.

So I convert the model using

```
tensorflowjs_converter  --input_format=tf_saved_model --output_format=tfjs_graph_model --signature_name=serving_default --saved_model_tags=serve /content/inference_graph/saved_model /mobilenet/web_model
```

and then I download the same.

I am now trying to use this on the browser using the following html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"> </script>
    <style>
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <img id="test1" src="test/IMG_20181228_102636.jpg" width="300" height="300" />
            <div id="test1_pred">WORKING</div>        
        </div>
        
    </div>

    <script>
        async function predict() {
            const model = await tf.loadGraphModel('http://localhost:8000/mobilenet/web_model/model.json');
            const img = document.getElementById('test1');
            const tfImg = tf.browser.fromPixels(img);
            const smalImg = tf.image.resizeBilinear(tfImg, [300, 300]);
            const resized = tf.cast(smalImg, 'int32');
            const t4d = tf.tensor4d(Array.from(smalImg.dataSync()),[1,300,300,3]);
            let predictions = await model.executeAsync(tf.cast(t4d, "int32"));
            console.log(predictions);
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            predict();
        }, 1000);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The error I get on console is

```
tfjs:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error in matMul: inputs must have the same rank of at least 2, got ranks 5 and 2.
    at xv (tfjs:17)
    at matMul_ (tfjs:17)
    at matMul__op (tfjs:17)
    at tfjs:17
    at tfjs:17
    at tfjs:17
    at t.e.scopedRun (tfjs:17)
    at t.e.tidy (tfjs:17)
    at $b (tfjs:17)
    at tfjs:17
```

I am at loss as to what is the error here. It does seem like it is to do with the ranks in the matrices, but not sure what is causing the mismatch.

How should I resize my images so that it is acceptable to the model ?

I am also posting my model in the gist in here [model.json](https://gist.github.com/anandsunderraman/3447c4df6423dd60d01b8fb57f570948)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why are you casting it and then converting it to a 4D tensor? What is the dimension of ```const smalImg``` and the dimension of the input layer of the model?

Comment: Could you please add your model summary to the question ?